# Appium and Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)

Tags: appium, android-6.0-marshmallow

Does Appium support Marshmallow? I'm trying to select a Platform Name of Marshmallow but it doesn't seem to contain it and I have the latest version of Appium installed....[image]

Comment: Could you try using the `capability` in your code and check?

Answer (score 7):

I don't have the 6.0 Marshmallow (API Level 23) as an option in the Appium app for Mac, but I was able to manually type the value 6.0 in and launching the server showed that the value was used correctly.

Simply type the `6.0` to the text box.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Yes It supports , u need to upgrade API 23 in SDK
Appium Vs 1.4.16.1

Comment: Its Good to upgrade. If you are working on Android M, then upgrade to API23

Comment: i installed all versions of the SDK but that still didn't resolve it for me unfortunately.  also i am running this on OS X, your screenshot is windows

Comment: Raj, what version of Appium are you using?